# get xml declaration in string through xdocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Can you please tell me how to get Xml declaration in string ?

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE KEA-publ PUBLIC "-//KLI//DTD KEA-BASIC//EN" "keabasic.dtd" [ 
<!ENTITY SLSD_158790_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw01.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158791_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw02.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158792_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw03.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158493_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw04.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158794_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw05.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158795_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw06.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158796_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw07.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158797_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw08.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158g98_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw09.gif" NDATA GIF>
<!ENTITY SLSD_158499_gif SYSTEM "IEL-Environment-109-Taiwan_aw10.gif" NDATA GIF>
]>
```

how to get above declaration part of xml file

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`XDocument.Declaration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to get the declaration.

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(filename);
var declaration = doc.Declaration
```

I think, you are looking for [`XDocument.DocumentType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.documenttype(v=vs.110).aspx) not `Declaration`, in case if you want get `InternalSubSet` use this.

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(filename);
var internalSubset = doc.DocumentType.InternalSubset;
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O0WJ1g)